# VSCode: remove lonely closing tags?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have a badly formatted html file, with floating/lonely closing tags. Something like:

```
<div>
    ...
</a>
</div>
```

The `</a>` is just there, without an opening tag.
There are other 'lonely' tags like this as well.

Is there an easy way to get all these lonely tags, and remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to use TidyHTML: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=anweber.vscode-tidyhtml

I just tested it with your snippet above and it does in fact remove closing tags without matching opening tags.

Just install the extension, press `F1` and run `TidyHtml`.